# Cross platform mobile gaming?

Tags: iphone, android, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm looking into game development across Android, iPhone AND Windows Phone 7, and i was wondering if anyone knows of good solutions and the state of the solutions. I'm considering MonoTouch/Droid as a development platform. There are a bunch of questions here:

1. Does XNATouch support MonoDroid?
2. Does XNATouch have basic 3D support? (read: textured animated models)
3. Are there any other options that have WP7 support

Please note, that i am fully aware of Unity, Airplay and other SDKs that support 2 of the 3 platforms, but i'm really hoping that there is a nice solution that fits all three without having to write a graphics abstraction layer ( due to project time constraints ).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that i also emailed the guys from Novell on this and some of my questions were answered:

1. Yes, it does

2. Not really, it's still a work in progress

Comment: By now you have probably discovered MonoGame which basically has all of the above.

Answer (score -2):

http://www.phonegap.com/ ? And all 3 should support opengl

Comment: Windows Phone 7 does not support OpenGL - XNA/Silverlight and C# only, and phonegap is for HTML/JS stuff, which is not sufficient for writing 3D mobile games. I met the guys from PhoneGap at a mobile conference last month, and while it's a really interesting product, it's not really targeted at 3D game development.

Answer (score -3):

maybe have a look at http://www.openframeworks.cc/. Doesn't support windows phone, though.

Comment: The question was explicitly for something that also supports windows phone, so your answer is not useful.